# Faceting on XML tag values

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I want to do faceting on xml tags, and sub faceting on the tag values, I have an xml documents like below

```
<TermiteJServiceResponse>
  <EntityTypeHit type="DRUG">
    <HitCollection>
      <Hit type="DRUG" id="CHEMBL1201288">
        <Name>Dantrolene</Name>
      </Hit>
      <Hit type="DRUG" id="CHEMBL286398">
        <Name>Propylene Glycol</Name>
      </Hit>
      <Hit type="DRUG" id="GXC376D7F8C0E7A0C3787E8A2384DC56E80">
        <Name>PEG400</Name>
      </Hit>
    </HitCollection>
  </EntityTypeHit>
  <EntityTypeHit type="COMPOUNDS">
    <HitCollection>
      <Hit type="COMPOUNDS" id="A-409912.5">
        <Name>A-409912.5</Name>
      </Hit>
      <Hit type="COMPOUNDS" id="A-409912">
        <Name>A-409912</Name>
      </Hit>
    </HitCollection>
  </EntityTypeHit>
  <EntityTypeHit type="GENE">
    <HitCollection>
      <Hit type="GENE" id="TRH">
        <Name>thyrotropin-releasing hormone</Name>
      </Hit>
    </HitCollection>
  </EntityTypeHit>
  <EntityTypeHit type="BIOPROC">
    <HitCollection>
      <Hit type="BIOPROC" id="BP70302">
        <Name>infusion</Name>
      </Hit>
      <Hit type="BIOPROC" id="D009200">
        <Name>Myocardial Contraction</Name>
      </Hit>
      <Hit type="BIOPROC" id="BP70198">
        <Name>cmax values</Name>
      </Hit>
      <Hit type="BIOPROC" id="D001835">
        <Name>Body Weight</Name>
      </Hit>
      <Hit type="BIOPROC" id="D062186">
        <Name>Arterial Pressure</Name>
      </Hit>
      <Hit type="BIOPROC" id="BP70209">
        <Name>contractility</Name>
      </Hit>
      <Hit type="BIOPROC" id="D006339">
        <Name>Heart Rate</Name>
      </Hit>
      <Hit type="BIOPROC" id="BP70316">
        <Name>intravenal</Name>
      </Hit>
    </HitCollection>
  </EntityTypeHit>
  <EntityTypeHit type="SPECIES">
    <HitCollection>
      <Hit type="SPECIES" id="D051381">
        <Name>Rats</Name>
      </Hit>
    </HitCollection>
  </EntityTypeHit>

</TermiteJServiceResponse>
```

I would like to facet based on in above document DRUGS and sub facet on Drug names and similarly Compounds and sub facet on Compound Name

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look a the MarkLogic Search Developer's Guide on "[Constrained Searches and Faceted Navigation](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/search-api#id_77403)".

Using Search API you can define constraints and facets (a type of constraint) using the `<search:options>` element. For each facet you will need to define a range index. Ideally you would use semantically named elements (`<DRUG>` instead of `<Hit type="DRUG">`) for simpler indexing; however, if this schema is not flexible, then you can [define a path range index](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/range_index#id_40666) over `//Hit[type="DRUG"]`, and reference it in your search options like:

```
<constraint name="Drug">
  <range type="xs:string" facet="true">
    <path-index>
      //Hit[type="DRUG"]
    </path-index>
  </range>
</constraint>
```

When you make a call to Search API using `search:search` or `search:resolve`, it will return a `search:response` element containing the results (snippets) and constraints or facet values that you define in `<search:options>`.